# VBA Excel - Targeting userform controls

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make code that, depending on an integer (which loops from 0 to 4), changes the targeted userform label. I've tried using

E.g

```
Public placeholderLabel as label 

sub test()
    if loopInt = 1

         set placeholderLabel = userForm1.labelTestA

    elseif loopInt = 2 then

       set placeholderLabel = userForm1.LabelTestB

    End if 
    placeholderLabel.caption "Woohoo!")
end sub
```

I've tried userform1.controls.LabelTestA and this did not do anything.

My intention was to be able to loop from 0 to 4 and then depending on the loopInt change 1 of the 5 labels. At this point it would have been way easier for me to just repeat the 5 assignments instead of looping 0 to 4 and changing the placeholders...but I want to understand *why* it is that my assignments to these userform objects isn't working. Very frustrating!

Comment: this is a good opportunity for `Select Case/End Select` instead of `If/ElseIf/End If`

Comment: Exactly what happens when you run your code?

Comment: `userForm1.Controls("labelTest" & Chr(65 + loopInt)).Caption = "Woohoo"` if your labels are named ...A, ,...B, ..C etc. and loopInt begins at zero.

Answer (score 1):

`placeholderLabel.caption "Woohoo!")` is improper. try `placeholderLabel.caption = "Woohoo!"`

If the name of your control is "myControl" then `UserForm1.Controls("myControl")` will get you the object